# SQL limit number of returned rows for each specified column value, in single query

Tags: mysql, sql

MySQL version 5.7

TABLE: Name, categoryID.

Is it possible to select only a specified amount of rows from each categoryID?

Something like this:

SELECT * FROM table1

*Pseudo: LIMIT 10 WHERE categoryID = 5
LIMIT 50 WHERE categoryID = 8*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a version of MySql that does not support window functions you can do it with a correlated subquery in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT t.* FROM tablename t
WHERE t.categoryID IN (5, 8)
AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename WHERE categoryID = t.categoryID AND name < t.name) < 
    CASE t.categoryID
      WHEN 5 THEN 10
      WHEN 8 THEN 50
    END
```

If you want results for all `categoryID`s then you can remove the condition `t.categoryID IN (5, 8)` from the `WHERE` clause and list all the `categoryID`s in the `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT t.* FROM tablename t
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename WHERE categoryID = t.categoryID AND name < t.name) < 
    CASE t.categoryID
      WHEN 5 THEN 10
      WHEN 8 THEN 50
      WHEN .....
    END
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=03f887d5a0b330322ecd149e8d3018a8).

Note that I assume that the column `name` is the primary key or unique in the table.
If this is not the case then you should use the primary key of the table in the above queries instead of `name`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by categoryid order by categoryid) as seqnum 
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 5;
```